# java, android: onActivityResult with different parameters in one activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-calendar

I have one activity where i use two onActvityResults

one for the `CalendarView`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent)
```

one for the retrieving of events in Google Calendar:

```
    @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

How do i have these two in one activity? Thanks!

Comment: simply check the value of requestCode inside the onActivityResult method and you are good to go. The request code can be set different for the two activities at the time of calling them using intent

Comment: the activity that calls `setResult(); finish();` does not care what the name of the Intent parameter is

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not properly understood the concept! This might help you to understand **onActivityResult**.

By using `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` you can **start** another Activity and then **receive a result** from that Activity in the `onActivityResult()` method.So `onActivityResult()` is from where you start the another Activity.

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` check the params here. request code is there to filter from where you got the result. so you can identify different data using their requestCodes!

**Example**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // Use a unique request code for each use case 
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE = 0x9988; 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Create an Intent to start AnotherActivity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);

            // Start AnotherActivity with the request code
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE);
        }

        //-------- When a result is returned from another Activity onActivityResult is called.--------- //
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // First we need to check if the requestCode matches the one we used.
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE) {

                // The resultCode is set by the AnotherActivity
                // By convention RESULT_OK means that what ever
                // AnotherActivity did was successful
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the result from the returned Intent
                    final String result = data.getStringExtra(AnotherActivity.EXTRA_DATA);

                    // Use the data - in this case, display it in a Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // AnotherActivity was not successful. No data to retrieve.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`AnotherActivity`  <- This the the one we use to send data to `MainActivity`

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

        // Constant used to identify data sent between Activities.
        public static final String EXTRA_DATA = "EXTRA_DATA";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

            final View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            // When this button is clicked we want to return a result
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Create a new Intent as container for the result
                    final Intent data = new Intent();

                    // Add the required data to be returned to the MainActivity
                    data.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, "Some interesting data!");

                    // Set the resultCode to Activity.RESULT_OK to 
                    // indicate a success and attach the Intent
                    // which contains our result data
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data); 

                    // With finish() we close the AnotherActivity to 
                    // return to MainActivity
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // When the user hits the back button set the resultCode 
            // to Activity.RESULT_CANCELED to indicate a failure
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**Note** : Now check in `MainActivity` you `startActivityForResult` there you specify a `REQUEST_CODE`. Let's say you want to call three different Activities to get results.. so there are three `startActivityForResult` calls with three different **REQUEST_CODE**'s. REQUEST_CODE is nothing but a unique key you specify in your activity to uniquely identify your `startActivityForResult` calls.

Once you receive data from those Activities you can check what is the REQUEST_CODE, then you know ah ha this result is from this Activity.

It's like you send  mails to your lovers with a colorful covers and ask them to reply in the same covers. Then if you get a letter back from them, you know who sent that one for you. awww ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You have just one, but they should have different codes, that's how you can differentiate if the result is from Calendar view or Google Calendar or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `requestCode` parameter of `onActivityResult` method. Call `startActivityForResult` method for both the scenario using different requests code.

E.g.

```
private static int CALENDAR_VIEW_CALL = 1;
private static int CALENDAR_EVENTS_CALL = 2;

...

startActivityForResult(intent1, CALENDAR_VIEW_CALL);

...

startActivityForResult(intent1, CALENDAR_EVENTS_CALL);
```

Now in your `onActivityResult`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CALENDAR_VIEW_CALL) {
        //do the callback work for calendar view
    }
    else if (requestCode == CALENDAR_EVENTS_CALL) {
        //do the callback work after retrieving the events
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But you don't have methods with different parameters, you have the same method, with the same parameters, only the name of the parameters is different, and you can't do this in java, because the language doesn't really know which method is which.

You should follow the other answers and check the requestCode